# $\min\{X, Y\}$ is geometrically distributed according to parameter $1 - (1-p)^{2}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X,Y$ be independent from the parameter $0 < p < 1$ distributed random variable on a discrete probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb P)$. Show that $\min\{X,Y\}$ is geometrically distributed to $1-(1-p)^{2}$.

I am having trouble understanding what it is my end result has to be, in order to show that it is indeed geometrically distributed. I mean for a geometric distribution $\mathbb P(k) = p(1-p)^{k-1}$ for parameter $p$, but how exactly am I showing a geometric distribution?

$\mathbb P( \min\{X,Y\} > k)=\mathbb P((X>k) \cap (Y>k))$ and then what?

In terms of the parameter, I've got: $(1-(1-p)^{2})(1-(1-(1-p)^{2}))=p^{2}(2-p)^{2}$

I do not understand how the two work together...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
P(\min(X,Y) > k) &= P(X > k, Y>k) \\
&= P(X > k)P(Y>k) \\
&= P(X >k)^2 \\
&=((1-p)^2)^{k}
\end{align}
Hence the CDF is $1-((1-p)^2)^k=1-(1-\color{blue}{(1-(1-p)^2)})^k$

Hence it is a geometric distribution (we just have to compare with the CDF of a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)) with success probability $1-(1-p)^2.$

Comment: Thank you! Please just remind me why we can assume $P(X > k)P(Y > k)= P(X > k)^{2}$. And then adding on to that why would it be equal to $((1-p)^{2})^{k}$?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are IID. Also we have $P(X > k)=(1-p)^k$.

Comment: In the pre-text, it was only stated that the $X, Y$ are independent. Can I automatically assume IID?

Comment: they are both geometric distribution with probability $p$ isn't it?

Comment: But the OP didn't actually state that.